# Error processing method: 'Android.Gms.Tasks.CancellationToken Google.Places.FetchPhotoRequest::get_CancellationToken()'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api, google-places

I updated my project to use the Xamarin.Google.Android.Places v1.1.0.1 package from the NuGet package Manager.

But the project build fails after upgrading to the new Places package.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Places package and it's dependencies, deleting the bin and obj folders, but none of it really helped.

This is the following error that I amgetting while building the solution:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'Android.Gms.Tasks.CancellationToken Google.Places.FetchPhotoRequest::get_CancellationToken()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Google.Places.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Gms.Tasks.CancellationToken
```

Comment: Can you try to build your app in different configuration of "Linker Behavior" in the Android Project settings to "Don't Link" & then "Link All Assemblies" and let us know if you are getting the same error

Comment: The issue was that the latest stable GooglePlayServices APIs were not supported by the Xamarin.Google.Android.Places API. I added the following package versions of the required dependencies and the error was gone.

Comment: https://ibb.co/MZ6tbyD

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the latest stable GooglePlayServices APIs were not supported by the Xamarin.Google.Android.Places API. I added the following package versions of the required dependencies and the error was gone.

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Volley" Version="1.1.1.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Places">
  <Version>1.1.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Glide" Version="4.9.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Glide.DiskLruCache" Version="4.9.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Glide.GifDecoder" Version="4.9.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="71.1601.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" Version="71.1610.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Clearcut" Version="71.1600.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" Version="71.1600.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" Version="71.1600.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Phenotype" Version="71.1600.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places.PlaceReport" Version="71.1600.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" Version="71.1601.0-preview3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.AutoValue.Annotations" Version="1.6.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="GoogleGson" Version="2.8.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download">
  <Version>0.4.11</Version>
</PackageReference>
```